# Return index associated with x-value limits R

Tags: r, indexing

I have a large data-frame and need to return the index range associated with a given value in the data-frame.

A minimal example:

```
x = c(2:11)
x
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

How can I return the index of a given value in x?

For example, how do I return the index value of the number 3 in x (the desired output would be 2)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `==` to get a logical vector, then with `which` to return the position of TRUE value from the logical vector

```
which(x==3)
#[1] 2
```

---

Or another option is `match` which returns the first position of '3' in the 'x' vector

```
match(3, x)
#[1] 2
```